# No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description when inserting a document

Tags: mongodb, scala, observable, future

I'm following the [MongoDB Scala Drive Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/getting-started/quick-tour/) guide and trying to insert a document. But I keeping seeing the following message whenever I do so

> INFO: No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster
>   description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE,
>   serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=ds155695.mlab.com:55695,
>   type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing
>   out

Here is what my code looks like

```
val url: String = "mongodb://heroku_#######:#############@ds155695.mlab.com:55695/heroku_#########"
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(url)
val db: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("heroku_#####")
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = db.getCollection("omens")
println(collection)

val doc: Document = Document("_id" -> 3434, "name" -> "xxxxxx", "type" -> "yyyyyy")
val observable: Observable[Completed] = collection.insertOne(doc)
observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
  override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("Inserted")
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed")
  override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
})
```

If I change my code to use Futures, I get the same message. However, if I use the Await to explicitly wait for a time, its works. The following is defined in the Helpers.scala as suggested by the quick tour.

```
  trait ImplicitObservable[C] {
    val observable: Observable[C]
    val converter: (C) => String

    def results(): Seq[C] = Await.result(observable.toFuture(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    def headResult() = Await.result(observable.head(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    def printResults(initial: String = ""): Unit = {
      if (initial.length > 0) print(initial)
      results().foreach(res => println(converter(res)))
    }
    def printHeadResult(initial: String = ""): Unit = println(s"${initial}${converter(headResult())}")
  }
```

And if I do the following, it'll work and insert the document.

```
val result = collection.insertOne(doc).results()
```

But I find that a little suboptimal and want to use Futures or Observable. Can someone point what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the full stack trace

```
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ds155695.mlab.com:55695
com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Opening the AsynchronousSocketChannelStream failed
    at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.get(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.getOpen(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.get(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:57)
```

Comment: Do you have any firewall between the app and the heroku cluster? A timeout is most likely due to packets being dropped by the firewall before being allowed to the heroku server.

Comment: I do not think that is the case. I can insert documents using another clients. Plus, I can insert documents using the same app if I use Await

Comment: And I just tried switching the database to a local one. It gives me the same error so I highly doubt if its a Heroku or an mlab specific issue